# How to represent data in Component diagram

Tags: uml

Is there any option to represent data structure in component diagram. i can represent the sub modules in component as 'Parts'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data Structure cannot be represented in Component diagram, if you want to represent the data structure, then use the class diagram.